# 4D Linear system using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, solver

I have a linear system like `A * x = b` that I want so solve. The `numpy` solves it easily with `numpy.linalg.solve`.

But my `A` is a 4D-array of shape `(m, n, m, n)`, `b` is a 2D-array of shape `(m, n)` and I want to find `x` of shape `(m, n)`.
Actually I transform `A` into `Aexp` of shape `(m*n, m*n)`, and `b` into `bexp`  of shape `(m*n)` to find `xexp` and transform back to `x`.
My code is like

```py
Aexp = np.zeros((m*n, m*n))
Bexp = np.zeros(m*n)
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        Bexp[i*n + j] = B[i, j]
        for r in range(m):
            for s in range(n):
                Aexp[i*n + j, r*n + s] = A[i, j, r, s]
Xexp = np.linalg.solve(Aexp, Bexp)
X = np.zeros((n, m))
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        X[i, j] = Xexp[i*n+j]
```

But it's not nice. Is there a function like `X = solve(A, B)`? If not, how could I do without using loops?

How could I do with 3 index? `A.shape = (m, n, p, m, n, p)` and `B.shape = (m, n, p)`

Comment: The problem with creating a `solve` function for higher-order tensors is that the '*' in `A*x` isn't well-defined.  Is it a double dot product (`ijkl,lk->ij`) is it an inner tensor product(`ijkl, jk->il`), is it something else?  Different fields play fast and loose about what they mean based on what makes their models work best, which means one specific `solve` function is likely to get some branch of math or physics mad at you.  So if you're doing high-order tensor analysis, you're sort of on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a numpy.reshape can be suitable?

```
import numpy as np
m = 2
n = 3
A = np.zeros((m,n, m,n))
B = np.zeros((m,n))
Aexp = A.reshape((m*n, m*n))
Bexp = B.reshape((m*n))
```